# Is this proof of a binary representation rigorous?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, examples-counterexamples

From what I have seen so far, intro discrete math books usually provide a proof that every natural number can be uniquely expressed as a sum of distinct powers of $2$ in two steps: proving the (1) existence, and then (2) uniqueness. I believe that I have found a way that combines both statements, and I wonder if it may be used as a rigorous proof since it does not look "typical." 
**Claim:** 
Any natural number $N\geq1$ may be *uniquely* expressed as a sum $N=\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^{a_k}$, where $a_{1}<a_{2}<...<a_{n}.$ 
**Proof:** 
Suppose $\exists X\subset\mathbb{N} \ \ | \ \  X=\{N\in\mathbb{N}:N\neq\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^{a_k}$}, then, by the Well-Ordering Principle, there exists the smallest element $x\in X,$ which is the smallest counterexample. Therefore, suppose the claim is true for $x-1$. We need to rule out the possibility of $x=1,$ since $1-1=0\ngeq1.$ Thus, 
*Basis case:* $1=2^{0}.$ 
Since the claim is true for $x-1$, 
$x-1=2^{a_1}+2^{a_2}+2^{a_3}+...+2^{a_n},\implies x=1+2^{a_1}+2^{a_2}+2^{a_3}+...+2^{a_n}=2^0+2^{a_1}+2^{a_2}+2^{a_3}+...+2^{a_n}.$ 
If $\nexists a_i=0$ for $i= \{ 1,2,...,n\},$ then the binary representation for $x$ exists and is unique. Hence, we reach a contradiction, and the claim is true. 
If $\exists a_i=0$ for $i= \{ 1,2,...,n\},$ then $2^{0}+2^{a_i}=2^0+2^0=2^1.$ 
Similarly, if $\nexists a_i=1$ for $i= \{ 1,2,...,n\},$ then the binary representation for $x$ exists and is unique. 
However, once again, if $\exists a_i=1$ for $i= \{ 1,2,...,n\},$ then $2^{1}+2^{a_i}=2^1+2^1=2^2.$

Continuing like that, we either stop at a particular $a_i<n$ which was not used in the expression for $x-1$ (and get a unique representation), or finally run into the case $a_i>n$, which is obviously also unique as $a_i$ has not been used in an expression for $x-1$. Thus, since the binary representation for $x$ exists ($\Rightarrow \! \Leftarrow$), the claim is proven.